# Ruby On Rails helper for create grids

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, haml

i'm trying to create an helper for grids and i'm using this code:

**in app/helpers/application_helper.rb:**

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def grid_helper(names)
    names.each_slice(2) do |name1, name2|

      haml_tag 'div', class: 'column' do
        haml_tag 'div', class: 'thumb' do
          haml_concat link_to name1[:url] do
            image_tag name1[:thumb], alt: name1[:description], size: '36x36'
          end
        end

        haml_tag 'div', class: 'thumb' do
          haml_concat link_to name2[:url] do
            image_tag name2[:thumb], alt: name2[:description], size: '36x36'
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**calling on haml:**

```
#mydiv
  - games = [{thumb: 'foo', description: 'foobar', url: 'foo'}, {thumb: 'bar', description: 'foobarbaz', url: 'bar'}]
  - grid_helper(games)
```

**So this put in html:**

```
<div class="column">
  <div class="thumb">
    <a href="/">foo</a>
  </div>

  <div class="thumb">
    <a href="/">bar</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

The `link_to` don't working correctly and `image_tag` really don't works on my **helper**, someone can help?

**Obs:** I'm using Rails4, Ruby2 and sass/haml

Comment: Remove `p` before `link_to`

Comment: @Baldrick removed, but this changes nothing :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is on the following line:

```
haml_concat link_to name1[:url] do ...
```

The block is used by `haml_concat` instead of the `link_to`. You could rewrite it like that

```
haml_concat(link_to name1[:url] { image_tag name1[:thumb], alt: name1[:description], size: '36x36' })
```